# What is the random argument used with "rsync --server"?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I'm using RSYNC to backup files from two hosts to one other NAS and because of the amount of data to backup, the currently used settings of RSYNC etc. those two backups overlap currently. The NAS is running the following RSYNC processes right now:

```
root@[...]:~# ps axf | grep [r]sync
24899 ?        D    167:26  |   \_ /opt/bin/rsync --server -lHogDtpre.iLsfx [...] . /volume1/dasi_HOST1_vbox/DIR1/
24900 ?        D    123:39  |       \_ /opt/bin/rsync --server -lHogDtpre.iLsfx [...] . /volume1/dasi_HOST1_vbox/DIR1/
 5962 ?        S     33:15      \_ /opt/bin/rsync --server -lHogDtpre.iLsfx [...] . /volume1/dasi_HOST2_vbox/DIR2/
 5963 ?        D     12:25          \_ /opt/bin/rsync --server -lHogDtpre.iLsfx [...] . /volume1/dasi_HOST2_vbox/DIR2/
root@[...]:~#
```

**What's the argument `-lHogDtpre.iLsfx` and why is it the same for two different remote hosts? Does that contain any harm, like everything is handled by one RSYNC only and makes data transfer slower or alike?**

I thought it's some ID so that remote RSYNC processes know where to connect to or something like that. But that wouldn't make too much sense with two remote hosts getting the same ID. On the other hand, I didn't find any argument corresponding to the schema `-l[...]` in the manpage as well, so I guess it's something undocumented in combination with `--server`  only. That is documented to not be used externally etc.

Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: You can find out what the options mean by looking at the `rsync` man page. Short options can be combined, so this is equal to `-l -H -o` etc.

Comment: So RSYNC does that automatically for the remotely created processes? Because the calling script is NOT using any short option, always the long ones. What I excluded from the snippet above using `[...]` are some long options as well, I wouldn't have expected RSYNC to mix things automatically. You should create an answer to get the credits for point that out.

Comment: Yes, rsync automatically spawns another rsync process on the remote server. That's where your "cryptic" ps output comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s not a single switch. It is common for short options (single letter) on Linux software to be combined. So if you want to specify `-a -s -d -f`, you can also use `-asdf`. This also applies to `rsync`. It’s probably related to the option parsing library commonly used.

So you have here:

- l: --links, copy symlinks as symlinks
- H: --hard-links, preserve hard links
- o: --owner, preserve owner (super-user only)
- g: --group, preserve group
- D: same as --devices --specials, so:

  - --devices, preserve device files (super-user only)
  - --specials, preserve special files
- t: --times, preserve modification times
- p: --perms, preserve permissions
- r: --recursive, recurse into directories

…and after that the options don’t make a lot of sense so they probably have a different meaning in server mode.

You also often see this on the `rsync` client side: `rsync -avHAX /a /b`

You may wonder why there’s so many options. I’d say this is to make the invocation unambiguous even if the server-side `rsync` may have different default options. Lots of options are implied (for example `-a` expands to `-rlptgoD`, all of which are present in your server command line) or may be defaults.

Also note that not all “long options” have abbreviations, so they may also appear on the command line.